# Right justified table printer function

Tags: python, formatting

A challenge in the beginner book "Automate the boring stuff":

```
#! Python3

# Table printer
# Takes a list of lists of strings and displays in right-justified table
# assumption is inner lists contain same number items
# each inner list must be printed as a column

the_list = [["a", "bbbbbbbbb", "tttt"],
            ["d", "eeee", "ggggggggggg"],
            ["g", "hhh", "kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk"]]

def print_table(a_list):
    """
    Prints a 2d list as a right justified table where each column represents
    an inner list 
    """
    rows = len(the_list[0])
    columns = len(the_list)
    column_widths = [0 for i in range(columns)]
    # find longest string in each inner lists(or column)
    for i in range(len(column_widths)):
        longest = 0
        for item in a_list[i]:
            if len(item) > longest:
                longest = len(item)
        column_widths[i] = longest

    # store strings in list
    print_row = ["" for i in range(rows)]
    # iterate over lists to produce strings with correct formatting
    for a in range(rows):
        for i in range(columns):
            print_row[a] = print_row[a] + a_list[i][a].rjust(column_widths[i]
                                                             + 4)
    for item in print_row:
        print(item)

print_table(the_list)
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your post to reflect the review you are looking for. OK?  isn't enough to reflect what you are looking for.

Comment: Well I've been chastised in the past for doing just that tbh :/ Any suggested improvements at all are welcome. Many times after I post here, someone arrives and writes a script half the length to perform the same task. In addition, I'm assuming some other beginners may stumble across this in the future, this had me strangely frustrated for a while.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way that you find `rows` and `columns` is good. You can't iterate through the lists so this approach is good.
However using them for your comprehensions is *bad*.

The name `a_list` is not descriptive, and quite poor.
`table` whilst generic is much better.

Your comprehensions and loops are actually rather poor.
Your comprehensions are used as if you are initialize an array in say C.
But this is Python, not C.

You should also use the builtins. The way you find the longest in a list can be changed to use `max` instead.
And if you use a comprehension to change all the strings to their length then you could make `column_widths` a comprehension.

```
column_widths = [max(len(cell) for cell in column) for column in table]
```

Your print row is also quite strange.
Instead of `print_row[a] = print_row[a] +` you should use `print_row[a] +=` but this can be done in a list comprehension too.
As you're joining the items by nothing you can 'wrap' the comprehension with `''.join`.
And the comprehension would just be the indexing the table and justifying you're already doing.
This can result in:

```
print_row = ["" for i in range(rows)]
for row in range(rows):
    print_row[row] = ''.join(
        table[col][row].rjust(column_widths[col])
        for col in range(columns)
    )

for item in print_row:
    print(item)
```

From this you should notice that there is not much point in adding to a list, if you're just going to print it later anyway.
And so you can merge these two loops together and remove the `print_row` comprehension.

Also I'd change the `rjust` call to not add 4 spaces, as that indents the table, which looks kinda ugly.
And you can add a space between each column by using `' '.join` instead.
This can result in the function:

```
def print_table(table):
    rows, columns = len(table[0]), len(table)

    column_widths = [max(len(cell) for cell in column) for column in table]
    for row in range(rows):
        print(' '.join(table[col][row].rjust(column_widths[col]) for col in range(columns)))
```

Comment: Since the `table` parameter is in a column-major arrangement, you should rename the dummy variables: `column_widths = [max(len(cell) for cell in column) for column in table]`.

Comment: Thanks so much, I appreciate that! I've had a close look at list comprehensions this morning (which also led to me sets) after reading your post. Interesting stuff.

Comment: How would you make the 1st column R-justified and the remaining L-justified? It seem that the list comprehension make that hard to accomplish, in this case.

Comment: @not2qubit I'd use `str.format`, if you ask another - on-topic - question then I could show you.